# Manipulating a QGradient to follow a path

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, qt4.7

I am using Qt to draw something that looks like a pipe which can curve and arc using a QPainterPath.  I use a QLinearGradient to fill the pipe in order to give it a three dimensional look.  What I can't figure out is how to curve/arc the pipe and have the gradient *follow* those same curves so that the 3D effect remains.  Any thoughts?

In other words, the color stops on the QGradient need to rotate along with the curves in the path.

Comment: Are you using QGraphicsView Framework ?.

Comment: Not currently.  But I could be.  I intentionally left the question a bit vague as I can refactor my code as necessary and want any and all ideas!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see from qt [examples](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/painting-painterpaths.html) the gradient with which you fill your path is all same. So you define a nice gradient, than a path and add the gradient to all your shape with a code like this:

```
QLinearGradient myGradient;
QPen myPen;

QPainterPath myPath;
myPath.cubicTo(c1, c2, endPoint);

QPainter painter(this);
painter.setBrush(myGradient);
painter.setPen(myPen);
painter.drawPath(myPath);
```

The hardest part is define a pipe that moves smootly...Could you share your code so we can see your problem?